# How to denote a function parameter holding a var

Tags: clojure, naming-conventions

I have some functions that receive a var as a parameter and I would like to mark the parameter name in a standard way to denote it is a var (so you remember to use @ to get its value for instance).

Is there some naming convention for that? Would you still use the *...* thing?

(in case you are wondering the use case is implementing a simple Scheme interpreter as an eval function that I call repeatedly in emacs/cider so I need the "environment" to persist throughout the repl interaction)

EDIT - Code example

```
;; given a scheme expression exp and an environment env
;; evaluate it based on the expression type
;; (note that env is a var)
(defmulti eval-exp (fn [exp env] (-dispatch exp)))

;; method to evaluate variables
;; (note that env is a var)
(defmethod eval-exp :variable [exp env]
    (lookup-variable-value exp @env))

;; helper function to lookup var in environment env
;; (note that env is a value)
(defn lookup-variable-value [var env]
     (if (= env the-empty-environment)
         (throw (Exception. (str "Unbound variable " var)))
         (if-let [value (get-var var env)]
             value
             (recur var (enclosing-environment env)))))
```

I'd like to differentiate the parameter env (the var) from the parameter env (the value)

Comment: Post current code example.

Comment: The "\*...\*" thing is for dynamic vars - see https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide#earmuffs-for-dynamic-vars

Comment: @FrankC. I've added an example in the question

Comment: btw - a `var` is a pretty generic thing. if i have `(def answer 42)`, then `answer` is a var. mutability will depend on what the var is bound to

Comment: The thing here is that I need to pass this var holding the interpreter environment around to multiple functions, some of which just need the value (e.g., to read a variable in it) some of which really need the var to modify it and it feels weird to just call the function parameter "env" both when it represent a var and when it represents a value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably, you want to mark that your variable should implement `clojure.lang.IDeref` interface, i.e. that it's a [ref](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/ref), an [atom](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/atom) or any other `deref`able thing.

As far as I know, there is no specific convention to name `deref`able variables in Clojure. Of course, you could always invent your own convention, but I can see another possible solution for your problem.

Consider using standard type hints, like:

```clj
(defmethod eval-exp :variable [exp ^IDeref env]
  (lookup-variable-value exp @env))
```

or even

```clj
(defmethod eval-exp :variable [exp ^Atom env]
  (lookup-variable-value exp @env))
```

Type hints were designed to help Clojure compiler optimize code to avoid reflections, but no one said you can't use them to reduce human errors in your code.

**N.B.** Do not forget to import `clojure.lang.IDeref`/`clojure.lang.Atom` to use short `IDeref`/`Atom` instead of its full name.

Comment: I like this. I still ended up with a naming convention since I am just doing some toy examples, I started with adding a ! at the end of the name (e.g., env! ) but the settled on \*env* since it is automatically marked by my color scheme (I know...)